# Connecting SQL Server (local server) in VS code using xampp

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-code

Connecting my local server (created with xampp) with SQL Server in VS code, how is it possible?

```
{
    "mssql.connections": [
        {
            "server": "localhost",
            "database": "Haani",
            "user": "sa",
            "password": "",
            "authenticationType": "SqlLogin",
            "emptyPasswordInput": true,
            "savePassword": true
        }
    ]
}
```